# Open API 3 spec generation - ASP.Net Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, openapi, swagger-2.0, nswag

Is there support in Swashbuckle or NSwag Nuget packages to generate OpenAPI spec 3 compliant definition for APIs written in ASP.Net Web API 2 (.Net framework 4.7).

I tried using Swashbuckle and NSWag Nuget packages but I could get Swagger 2.0 compliant swagger.json.

Thank you!